# How is Drupal Planet realised?

Tags: feeds

How is the [Drupal Planet](http://drupal.org/planet) realised?
I found the [Planet installation profile](http://drupal.org/project/planet), but it seems to be dead (the Git instructions tab is empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal planet is built upon the core [aggregator](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/aggregator) module, blogs are required to set up a special feed (generally tagging it drupal-planet) to be imported in the list.

That should be pretty simple to reproduce: [What is Planet Drupal and how do I get added?](http://drupal.org/about/drupal-planet)